# Matlab error: The left hand side is initialized and has an empty range of indices. However, the right hand side returned one or more results

Tags: matlab

I'm working with code written by a previous developer. This code he has written, is available to me:

```
xDim = 4; zDim = 2;

storageModel{m_Z,1} = Z;
storageModel{m_dT,1} = T;

if k==1, %---assign values for first scan
    if monte==1,
        storageEstimates = [];
        storageHeadings = [];
    end
    storageModel{m_X, 1} = X;
    initializeOnlyTimeDependentMatrices = 0;
    storageModel{m_modelCode, 1} = mm_CV;
    [storageModel] = InitializeMotionModel(storageModel, k, initializeOnlyTimeDependentMatrices, xDim, zDim);
else if previousT ~= T,
        initializeOnlyTimeDependentMatrices = 1;
        [storageModel] = InitializeMotionModel(storageModel, k, initializeOnlyTimeDependentMatrices, xDim, zDim);
    end
end

[storageModel] = calculate(storageModel(:,1), stepCode);
X = storageModel{m_X, 1};
```

But the files where he initialized the cellArray named `storageModel`, is missing from version control. I'm told he forgot to commit it and nobody has a copy of it.

I tried initializing the cellArray like this:

```
m_Z = [0;0];
m_dT = [];
m_v = [0;0];
m_P = [0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;0 0 0 0;];

storageModel{1,1} = m_Z;
storageModel{2,1} = m_dT;
storageModel{3,1} = m_v;
storageModel{4,1} = m_P;
```

But on running it, in the first snippet of code I posted above, I get the error:

```
??? The left hand side is initialized and has an empty range of indices.
However, the right hand side returned one or more results.

Error in ==> CalculationHandler at 7
storageModel{m_Z,1} = Z;
```

I know for a fact that `m_Z` and `Z` are supposed to be `[0;0]`. I also know for a fact that this code `storageModel{m_Z,1} = Z;` was working earlier, so it is not the assignment of `Z` that is wrong. It is the way I initialized the cellArray that is wrong. Could you help in figuring out the correct way to initialize it or at least in interpreting the meaning of the error message? I've googled the error message, but nothing helpful turned up.

**p.s:** The original author was trying to store a bunch of matrices in a column of a cellArray. The matrices in every column represented the values required for a particular motion model.

**Update:** My 'fact' of `m_Z` being a [0;0] matrix, is wrong.

Comment: If `m_Z` is `[0;0]` then `storageModel{m_Z,1}` is not valid in MATLAB... So one of your facts is wrong. I can only get your error by trying `storageModel{[],1}=...` in other words the problem is the value of `m_Z` (which is empty i.e. `[]`)

Comment: `m_Z` is actually an indicator that it is a position where the `Z` matrix is stored in the `storageModel`. So if `m_Z` shouldn't initially be a matrix, then I assume `m_Z` would be an integer indicating which row of the cell array contains the `Z` matrix? Basically, I have to be able to assign the `Z` matrix to it at any time, any number of times, using this `storageModel{m_Z,1} = Z;` and also be able to get the `Z` matrix whenever I want, using this `Z = storageModel{m_Z, 1};`

Comment: so check the value of `m_Z` after you get that error. I'll bet it's `[]` in which case there's your error. You need to fix the code the assigns to `m_Z`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `m_Z` etc. were actually just ordinary numbers which indicated the position of an element in a cell array. So all I had to do was this:

```
m_dT = 1;
m_X = 2;
m_F = 3;
m_G = 4;
m_v = 5;
m_P = 6;
m_Q = 7;
m_H = 8;
m_I = 9;
m_w = 10;
m_Z = 11;
```

The cell array was being initialized in one part of the code like this  `storageModel{1,1} = 0;`. Initialization required only this much. The addition of more rows automatically happened in various parts of the code like this:

```
storageModel{m_Z,1} = Z;
storageModel{m_dT,1} = T;
```

Like Dan answered in the comments, the problem was that `m_Z` was being assigned as an empty matrix initially, and then I was trying to assign `Z` to it, which was a matrix of size 2x1. The size mismatch between the matrices was the cause of the error:

```
??? The left hand side is initialized and has an empty range of indices.
However, the right hand side returned one or more results.
```

Once the matrix of the correct size got assigned to row 11 of `storageModel` (11, because I kept `m_Z = 11;`), then there was no issue with assigning `storageModel{m_Z,1} = Z;` or vice versa `Z = storageModel{m_Z,1};`.

Thank you Dan!